# How to Remove URLs from Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I first connected my .com domain to a Blogger blog and wrote on the blog for three months and manually indexed about a hundred url in Google Console. Later, I bought a hosting and connected my domain to the WordPress site and removed the blog urls from Google through the removal tool. Now, after a few months, the urls of the blog and the site in Google Console were combined, and the old links of the blog are redirected to the domain in Google Console, and my wordpress website urls in Google have decreased drastically. Please guide me, how can I completely delete old blog links that no longer exist from Google Console?

Comment: What do you mean by connected your domain to blog ?  And do the old pages still exist ?

Comment: At first, I connected my domain to the Blogger using the Cloudflare, and after a few months, I connected my domain to my wordpress website, and then I deleted the blog, so none of the old pages exist anymore. Now, when I try to index the urls of my new site in the console, it says that this url exists in Google. But in fact, only three pages, that is, less than thirty urls from my site, have been indexed in the Google search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You really have to look at the GSC to see if there are any issues.  But you have to be sure that

1. The old URLs map onto your new site
2. Or they redirect to your new site
3. And that they do not exist.  Click on the links to verify.

To remove the old URLs, you can use the [Outdated Content Removal Tool](https://search.google.com/search-console/remove-outdated-content)

> Guidelines
>
> This tool works only for pages or images that have already been modified or removed from the web.
>
> To remove personal information or content with legal issues that still exist on a page, submit a legal request instead.